# How to Query (SumProduct) from Two Tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables HOUR contains the hour for 3 parts (A0001,B0001,C0001) with  different TYPE (A,B,C) and PART contains the EAU of 3 parts (A0001,B0001,C0001) from KEYID-29395:

[image]

I would like to have the total hour for the 3 different type, when KEYID=29395 is selected using the sumproduct

```
TYPEA_TOTAL_HOUR = 1*100 + 4*200 + 7*300 
TYPEB_TOTAL_HOUR = 2*100 + 5*200 + 8*300
TYPEC_TOTAL_HOUR = 3*100 + 6*200 + 9*300
```

[image]

How could I achieve this using SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOIN the two tables and AGGREGATE like this:

```
select
    a.keyid,
    sum(a.typea * b.eau) typea_total_hour,
    sum(a.typeb * b.eau) typeb_total_hour,
    sum(a.typec * b.eau) typec_total_hour
from hour a
join part b
on a.partid = b.partid
and a.keyid = b.keyid
group by a.keyid;
```

Comment: thank you very much - this will help me a lot as many of my calculations are similar to this.  I often just load everything to Excel and use Excel functions to do the math.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE HOUR (KEYID INT, PARTID CHAR(5), TYPEA INT, TYPEB INT, TYPEC INT)

INSERT HOUR VALUES (29395, 'A0001', 1, 2, 3), (29395, 'B0001', 4, 5, 6), (29395, 'C0001', 7, 8, 9)

CREATE TABLE PART (KEYID INT, PARTID CHAR(5), EAU INT)

INSERT PART VALUES (29395, 'A0001', 100), (29395, 'B0001', 200), (29395, 'C0001', 300)

SELECT H.KEYID, SUM(TYPEA*EAU) AS TYPEA, SUM(TYPEB*EAU) AS TYPEB, SUM(TYPEC*EAU) AS TYPEC
FROM HOUR H
INNER JOIN PART P ON H.KEYID=P.KEYID AND H.PARTID=P.PARTID
GROUP BY H.KEYID
```

Comment: Thank very much cloudsafe